# Firebase cloud function is not sending push when user created new document

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { firestore } = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const fcm = admin.messaging();

exports.senddevices = functions.firestore
.document("event/{uid}")
.onCreate( async (snapshot) => {
  const uid = snapshot.get("assigned_author_id");

  const token = await firestore.collection("users").get(uid).get("token");


  const name = snapshot.get("name");
  const description = snapshot.get("description");
  const message = {
    data: {
      name: name,
      description: description,
      uid: uid,
    },
    token: token,
  };
  return fcm.send(message);
});
```

I have created firebase cloud function, when user add new event this cloud function should trigger push event. When onCreate event is triggered, I wanted to get token from users collection. But I when I deploy this code it stop working and I can't receive any push.
Everything is working well if I remove

> const token = await firestore.collection("users").get(uid).get("token");

this line and hardcode user token

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Not sure where I can see an error for firebase cloud function. I attached image to the post, path is correct

Comment: "it stop working" is really hard to help with. The chances that someone can help are much better if you debug the code yourself, and tell us the results of that. So log the value of every variable on every line, and then check the output of that. When you do that, which is the first line/value that isn't what you expect it to be?

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed it. just replaced await firestore -> await admin.firestore()